# Using Websockets in Node.js to create a real time HTML 5 canvas with fabric.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, fabricjs

Has anyone worked on a real time project with fabric.js/socket.io?
My canvas works fine but somewhere along, the canvas just turns white for one user (the other user's canvas appears normal). The objects are still on the canvas but they are white. Then after a minute the canvas's objects turn back to their original color.

I am simply serializing the canvas sending it to the server and broadcasting the canvas to all clients(except user). Canvas is then cleared, de-serialized and loaded on to the canvas.

How do I achieve a smooth real time canvas between 2 clients without any of these unexpected canvas glitches! I'm not sure if I am using socket.io or fabric.js wrong. Please advice me!

```js
//client side code

var socket = io();
socket.on('canvas', function(canvasobj){
 canvas.clear();
 canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasobj, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options){
  var canvasStr = JSON.stringify(canvas);
  socket.emit('canvas', canvasStr);
});
```

```js
//node.js code

 io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('canvas', function(canvasobj){    
        socket.broadcast.emit('canvas', canvasobj);
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but try

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  var canvasStr = JSON.stringify(canvas);
  socket.emit('canvas', canvasStr);
});
```